# Can't change width of table data element

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm posting a screenshot of the element in question. You should be able to see, I am applying element-specific styling removing all margin, padding and setting the width to 0px. No matter what I do, this table data element is abnormally large. I want to significantly reduce its width, but it won't listen to me. I have the feeling this is some obscure HTML algorithm that I know nothing of but can't say. Any ideas?

[image]

Update: The answer was that HTML will make sure the table data elements take up the entire width of the table, no matter if you try to narrow individual elements (so in essence, it was some weird HTML algorithm or functionality). That said, I will accept the answer below because it is so thorough it should cover the other possible issues people may run into.

Comment: Post your code, not a screenshot.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think it covers the problem you were having, and various other scenarios. Feel free to let me know.

Comment: I've been having a similar issue. Changing an `input` `max-width` from `%` to `px` solved (removed) the extra wasted margin/padding inside the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some obscurity to how the width of a table cell (`<td>`) is defined, as [official documentation is unclear and allows some behavior to be defined by the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926939/what-is-the-default-width-of-an-html-table-cell-td). But here are a few characteristics that appear stable across the spectrum of browsers.

#### Managing the Width of HTML Table Cells <td>

1. **Table with Single Cell**
   In a table that consists of a single cell – in other words, a table with one column and one row – where the width hasn't been explicitly defined in the `<table>` element, the width can be controlled directly by the `<td>` element.

   This won't work (the `td` rule will be ignored):

   ```
   table { width: 100%;}
   td {width: 300px;}
   ```

   The `width: 300px` fails because the `<table>` element has a defined width.

   However, this will work:

   ```
   /* table { width: 100%;} */
   td {width: 300px;}
   ```

   [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/zqmfta7y/)

---

2. **Table Column with Multiple Cells**
   To set the width of a table cell in a column with multiple cells the entire column must be adjusted. Any widths assigned to the individual `<td>`s will be ignored. Simply adjust the width of the table to adjust the width of the `<td>`s in the column.

   [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/zqmfta7y/1/)

---

3. **Table with Multiple Columns and Multiple Rows**
   To set the width of a table with multiple columns and rows, the [Table Column Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) (`<col>`) is ideal because it targets individual columns.

   [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/zqmfta7y/2/)

---

The problem described in the question involves a table cell that won't accept a shorter width assignment. The first realization here is that the table cell by default expands to fill 100% of the column width allotted ([learn more about <td> default width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926939/what-is-the-default-width-of-an-html-table-cell-td)). The way to reduce the width of this cell is described above.

HOWEVER, I suspect that in some cases the person wanting to reduce the width of a table cell is actually trying to reduce the width of the content inside the cell (like an image or a form input). In these cases, adjusting the table may be unnecessary. All that would be needed is to adjust the width of the content itself, or its container (`div`, `span`, `figure`, etc.).

In this image, the width of the table cells are at 100%, but the width of the input fields vary.

[image]

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/zqmfta7y/4/)

---

### colspan

If in fact the need is to reduce the width of a single cell within a column of multiple cells, then you may want to consider the [`colspan`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/th/colspan) attribute. With `colspan`, columns can me merged making cells wider. Cells without `colspan` assigned will be shorter, and appear even shorter when their adjacent cells are hidden.

In this image, `display: none` has been applied to the bottom right cell of this 2-column table.

[image]

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/zqmfta7y/5/)

---

So, in the case of your table cell that won't budge, consider adjusting the width of the `<table>` element (if it's a single column table), assign and adjust a `<col>` element (if it's a multi-column table), adjust the width of the content directly (if that's the only element you want adjusted), or use `colspan`.

Sorry I can't be more specific about the exact solution in your case. No code was provided for review. But hopefully one of these methods helps you out.

Comment: Thanks so much for this extremely thorough answer! I will definitely consult it into the future as I try and debug any table issues I may run into in the future. However, I found the issue to be caused by the fact that the table data elements would take up the entire width of the table regardless of what the width was set to for an individual element. I created a hidden table data element and set its width to take the space up, less than ideal solution though but the only one that seems reasonable.