# Make all cells in a table have the same width equal to widest cell width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to have the same width on all cells in a table that is equal to the widest cell's width without using fixed widths.

Comment: Here's an answer I recently posted on table cell width behavior. Hope it helps. [Managing the Width of HTML Table Cells <td>](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31822882/3597276)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>short</td>
        <td>longer</td>
        <td>the longest cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
var max = 0,
    $cells = $('td');

$cells.each(function () {
    var width = $(this).width();
    max = max < width ? width : max;
});

$cells.each(function () {
    $(this).width(max);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uqvuwopd/1/

[EDIT]

As @connexo pointed out in the comments some more logic is needed to handle the case when the table would be larger than its maximum size:

```
var max = 0,
    $cells = $('td');

$cells.each(function () {
    var width = $(this).width();
    max = max < width ? width : max;
});

$table = $cells.closest('table');

if ($table.width() < max * $cells.length) {
    max = 100 / $cells.length + '%';
}

$cells.each(function () {
    $(this).width(max);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uqvuwopd/3/

[EDIT]

And this is a version based on ECMA5 that doesn't require jQuery:

```
var max = 0,
    cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(cells, function(cell){
    var width = cell.offsetWidth;
    max = max < width ? width : max;
});

var table = document.querySelector('table'),
    uom = 'px';

if (table.offsetWidth < max * cells.length) {
    max = 100 / cells.length;
    uom = '%';
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(cells, function(cell){
    cell.setAttribute('style','width:' + max + uom);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uqvuwopd/4/

Comment: This works only as long as there is enough space available. https://jsfiddle.net/uqvuwopd/2/ If not, the cells with less content will ignore the `width` you applied.

Comment: I don't understand what "it" refers to in your comment.

Comment: I meant that of course it works only as long as there is enough space available... The OP didn't require any special behaviour in that case :)

Comment: There was no necessity to "require special behaviour in that case" since they clearly stated they want a solution that creates equal width columns. The fact that they didn't talk about available horizontal resolution invalidates the requirement only in your interpretation.

Comment: `var max = 0,
    $cells = $('td'), $table = $cells.closest('table');

$cells.each(function () {
    var width = $(this).width();
    max = max < width ? width : max;
});

$table[0].width($cells.length*max);
$cells.each(function () {
    $(this).width(33.333333%);
});`

Comment: Is it possible to set at once also the min-width value of each cell?